# Как организовать фильтры

Tags: android, mysql

Здравствуйте. Приложение отправляет запрос на получение данных к серверу. И там происходит sql запрос - обычный select который выбирает все поля. Мне нужно чтоб он выбирал данные по определенному фильтру. Я ничего умного не придумал, а просто перебирал все возможные комбинации и давал им индексы 0, 1, 2, 3, и так далее. То есть получится так что у меня будет много ifов или switch case. Он у меня появится во первых в апи, во-вторых в приложении при получении данных. Как создать фильтр по умному чтоб обойтись всего лишь одним sql запросом. Никогда подобного не встречал, даже не знаю как так сделать. получается что у меня будет вариантов 20, то есть это всего будет 20 условий а это очень тупо.
вот к примеру [интернет-магазин](http://hard.rozetka.com.ua/ssd/kingston/c80109/v065/)
тут куча фильтров и куча вариантов, я уверен что у них один универсальный запрос. каким образом построить такой запрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гм... У меня сложилось впечатление что вы почему-то решили что в where запроса вы можете использовать только знак равенства. Это не верно. Почитайте например [тут](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/functions.html) про это.

Вообще в данном случае Вам надо сгенерировать правильный *where* для запроса на основе входных параметров. Например:

```
where_sql += "and((type_request=$type_request and $type_request < 4) or ($type_request = 4 and type_request<4))";
....
sql = "select * from table where (1=1)" + where_sql;
```

Comment: я знаю, что не только равенство может быть при использовании where.
можете объяснить пожалуйста что такое (1=1)? это условие которое всегда будет выполнятся? 
ну суть я понял, спасибо. попробую таким образом сделать

Comment: @Firespirit это чтоб не отрезать первый `and` в `where_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

мсье определенно знает толк ....
не нужно выбирать все поля, недостаточно данных чтоб написать все что нужно но если кратко то обычный select  с параметрами и условиями выбора,возможно понадобится составной запрос
вся выборка должна идти в запросе, не нужно из кода дополнительно фильтровать и прочие, все это лучше делать средствами sql
[where](http://www.dimonchik.com/sql-where.html)

Comment: что такое where я знаю. просто не понимаю как написать универсальный запрос. Например у меня есть поле "type_request", которое может принимать значения 1,2,3 и для него where нормально сработает, но если вдруг пользователь захочет отфильтровать одновременно по 1,2, или одновременно 2,3 и так далее, то каким образом тут сроить запрос?

Comment: нужно использовать логические операторы 
....
where type_request = 1 and type_request = 2

Comment: это не решит проблему, все-равно будет несколько условий и несколько запросов, а нужно чтоб был один запрос. Например, я получаю значение type_request, потом идет SELECT name,..... FROM table WHERE type_request='$type_request' так не получится.
А если делать как вы предложили то тогда будут ifы и появится несколько запросов: например:
if($type_request<4)
 SELECT name,..... FROM table WHERE type_request='$type_request'
else if($type_request==4)
SELECT name,..... FROM table WHERE type_request=1 and type_request=2
...
такое

Comment: можно пример таблицы и данных которые нужны, в крайнем случае  нужны подзапросы и объединения.  всю логику апи в один вопрос не уместить, почитай про LEFT, RIGHT, INNER, OUTER JOIN, IN

Comment: таблица состоит из полей coord1, coord2, type_request, price, seats

вот фильтр 1)  abs(coord1-$coord1)<5
фильтр 2) type_request(выше уже описал его работу)
фильтр 3) price >=$price
фильтр 4) seats>=$seats